# Getting image from input file and then add it as a background to a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a whack the mole game with Vanilla JS  and I am trying to make the person whack whatever he wants by letting them upload an image by input file but even after days of searching for any type of solution I had no luck.

HTML:

```
<input type='file' id='getval' name="background-image" />

<div class="game">
 <div class="hole hole1">
    <img class="mole">
 </div>
 <div class="hole hole2">
    <img class="mole">
 </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Vanilla:

```
document.getElementById('getval').addEventListener('change', readURL);
function readURL() {
  let file = document.getElementById("getval").files[0];
  document.getElementsByClassName('mole')[0].setAttribute("style", "background-image: url(" + file + ")");
  }
```

CSS:

```
.mole {
  background-image: url('');
}
```

The game works fine but the image uploaded does not appear:

[image]

If anyone could help me with this I will be more than welcome.

These project is part of #javascript30. I recreate them and change parts of it to practice Vanilla JS but I have been stuck for days with this one.

Comment: have you checked what `file` actually is at `let file =` - it probably won't be something you can use as a background-image url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this.

https://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/file-and-filereader.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

```js
const fileInput = document.getElementById('imageInput');

const images =  document.querySelectorAll('.mole');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', (e) =>{
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    fileReader.onload = function (){
        images[0].setAttribute('src', fileReader.result);
        // images[0].setAttribute('style', `background-image: url('${fileReader.result}')`);
    }
})
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: bisque;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.box{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  place-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

input{
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.images{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.mole {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <input type="file" id="imageInput" />
    <div class="images">
      <img class="mole" />
      <img class="mole" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Upinar! The only thing that I had to add so the image appear in every hole is by making a for loop: for (let i = 0; i< moles.length; i++) { moles[i].setAttribute('style', background-image: url('${fileReader.result}')); }